# will 32-bit altivec code work on 64-bit machine

Tags: altivec

I am porting altivec code from PPC to Intel architecture.
The current altivec code is 32-bit.
My Intel CPUs are 64-bit.

1. Will a 32-bit compiled code run on a 64-bit machine?
2. Can a 32-bit Altivec code be compiled for a 64-bit machine?

thnx

Comment: AltiVec code is PowerPC (or POWER) only - you will need to convert the AltiVec code to SSE if you want to run it on an Intel CPU.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I have downloaded the ALTIVEC library from Intel's website. Therefore I am assuming the SSE conversion has already been taken care of.

Comment: Are you aware of any 64-bit ALTIVEC for Intel processors?

Comment: AltiVec is part of the IBM PowerPC/POWER ISA. Intel has a similar SIMD architecture with SSE. You can not run AltiVec on Intel CPUs, and you can not run SSE on PowerPC/POWER CPUs. You would need to port the code from one architecture to the other, which generally means translating intrinsics or assembly code, depending on how the SIMD code was implemented.

Comment: Can you post a link to the "ALTIVEC library from Intel's website" ?

Comment: hi Paul:  Here is a link from Intel's website:   https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22957/Translation-of-PowerPC-AltiVec-SIMD-Macros-to-IA-32-AVX?product=74387

Comment: hi Paul: Here is a link from Intel's website: downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22957/…

Comment: OK - that is a *header* which uses macros etc to translate a subset of AltiVec intrinsics to equivalent SSE intrinsics (and in some cases, where no mapping exists, to scalar code). You could use that to get a quick but inefficient port of your existing AltiVec *source code* (assuming it uses intrinsics, and not assembly), but if you care about performance then you will probably want to port the code properly.

Comment: Paul,Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Paul: As I see it, the Altivec code provided by intel is for 32-bit CPUs.  I have a 64-bit CPU.  Will this code work for a 64-bit CPU?  If not, then what changes might need to be made?  Is there some compiler directive for GCC that can compile this code for 64-bit?  Thanks

Comment: It should mostly work - the main problem I see is that the author has made the classic mistake of assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(void *)`. He has also assumed that addresses are 32 bit when masking the low 4 bits of an address. So you'll need to fix those `Vxxx_ADDRESS` macros for a start.